# BASH: Pattern match not working

Tags: bash, pattern-matching

I am using BASH 3.2. I can execute the following from the command line:

```
$ build_number=23332
$ if [[ $build_number != +([0-9]) ]]
> then
> echo "Bad Build Number ($build_number). No CPU time for you!"
> else
> echo "Build Number ($build_number) is numeric"
> fi
Build Number (2332) is numeric"
```

If I change `build_number to`23332a`, this returns:

```
Bad Build Number (23332a). No CPU time for you!
```

Now, I'll try to put this into my shell script:

```
#! /bin/bash
...
#
# Set options
#
while getopts :hu:j:b:p: option
do
    case $option in
        p)  promotion_name="$OPTARG";;
        u)  jenkins_url="$OPTARG";;
        j)  job_name="$OPTARG";;
        b)  build_number="$OPTARG"
            if [[ $build_number != +([0-9]) ]]
            then
                error "Build Number must be numeric"
            fi
        ;;
        h)  printf "\n$USAGE\n"
            exit 0;;
        *)  error "Invalid Argument";;
    esac
done
shift $(( $OPTIND - 1 ))
```

When I try to execute my program, I get the following error:

```
$ ./promotion.sh -b 238d -jasdad
./promotion.sh: line 55: syntax error in conditional expression: unexpected token `('
./promotion.sh: line 55: syntax error near `+(['
./promotion.sh: line 55: `      if [[ $build_number != +([0-9]) ]]'
```

So, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable extended globbing:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

Comment: My default interactive shell is Kornshell where I first tested this and it worked fine. Then, realizing I should be running this in BASH, I started a BASH shell up and it still worked. However, being a Kornshell person, I set shell options `extglob` and `lithist` in my `.bashrc` file. This is why it worked on the command line and not in my shell script.

Answer (score 0):

well the most obvious thing is that the plus checks if the pre-ceeding character matches  the pattern  , here you have no pre-ceeding character put the plus after it

Comment: This is technically true, as the extended pattern (without `shopt -s extglob`) is being interpreted as a syntactically incorrect regular expression. However, given his assertion that it works correctly in his interactive shell, we can assume the extended glob is intended.